# Changing Images using extension Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have an extension installed on my Firefox browser which has a Javascript.

Also I have created a HTML file which has a Image tag with default image.

Everytime when I open that page, if my extension is enabled I want to change the Image which I have specified in my extension.

If the extension is disabled, then my default image should stay on that HTML page?

I need to perform something like

```
document.getElementById("check_image").src="Capture3.jpg"
```

in my extension JS.. so whenever I open a HTML page with Image ID "Check_Image", my extension JS should change the image to "Capture3.jpg".

Could you please tell me whether this can be done?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You're supposed to post some code. "If this can be done" is more opinion than anything, so your question will probably be closed.

Comment: What is that "extension"??

Comment: Does it have to be an extension? Creating a Userscript (Greasemonkey) would be much easier. Especially since you don't seem to have started one yet.

Comment: It doesn't have to be an extension.. I have my extension which runs on the browser.. so that extension when it finds a HTML page with element ID "Check_Image" it needs to change its source

Comment: That's bad. What if you open some other website which happens to use that ID on some element?

Comment: @DanMan I will have that ID name(may change later) specifically for me..! so it doesn't affect the other pages..

Comment: This sounds all weird. You should probably delete this and post a new question where you describe the problem you're trying to solve, instead of asking how to solve it the way you think it should be solved.

Comment: @DanMan I have achived it.. by taking the list of image tags that appear on the window..! thanks for making me to think :)

Comment: im accord with DanMan. This is a better approach to offer what you have already done and ask it or stuck to ask to solve the problem directly. You will beacoup more positive responses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes can be done. But you need to provide appropriate the relative path.

```
Folder
 -  mypage.html
 - Capture.jpg
```

then you can change the image using your code in .js

```
document.getElementById("check_image").src="Capture3.jpg"
```

Comment: Hi EOF, could you please elaborate?

Comment: yeah. first you need to check the directory/ parent folder of .html file. then you copy paste your "Capture3.jpg" in the same folder

Comment: in my extesnion's js file?